# Flatten multidimensional array of numbers recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Let's say I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [180] => Array
    (
        [400] => Array
        (
            [0] => 474
            [1] => 395
            [2] => 994
            [3] => 365
        )
    )
    [1] => 144
    [2] => 119
)
```

I would like to go though this array and generate a one dimensional array that contains all the numbers. In the loop, if we get an array, then the number is the corresponding array key.

I did something like this but it doesn't work:

```
function flatten_array($data) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result[] = $key;
            flatten_array($value);
        } else {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The resulting array I should get should be this one:

```
$result = Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 180
    [2] => 400
    [3] => 474
    [4] => 395
    [5] => 994
    [6] => 365
    [7] => 144
    [8] => 119
)
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please consider marking the answer which best solved your problem accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There are some helpful libraries in composer, for example this one: https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/iter

With this lib you can flatten the data the following way:

```php
$result = toArray(flatten($data));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know this can be done without using any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Without using libraries, such result can be achieved this way:

```php
function flattenArray(array $data) {
    $values = array_values($data);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge(flattenArray($value), $result);
        } else {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

P.S. Note the mistake in your original example:

```php
$result[] = $key;
flatten_array($value);
```

You call the recursive function without using its returned result.
And you assign the key instead.

Comment: This doesn't work. The array keys when we have a sub array is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't accumulate a result anywhere. You could return arrays and merge them, but to save allocation overhead I recommend using a single result array and passing it by reference into your recursive walk function. Here's a complete example:

```
function flatten_array($a) {
    function flatten($a, &$flat) {
        foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $flat[] = $k;
                flatten($v, $flat);
            }
            else {
                $flat[] = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    $flat = [];
    flatten($a, $flat);
    return $flat;
}

$a = [
    123,
    180 => [
        400 => [
            474,
            395,
            994,
            365,
        ]
    ],
    144,
    119
];

print_r(flatten_array($a));
```

If you expect your depth to be massive, you can do it iteratively to avoid an overflow. Note that this gives a breadth-first ordering:

```
function flatten_array($a) {
    $flat = [];

    for ($stack = [$a]; count($stack);) {
        foreach (array_pop($stack) as $k => &$v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $flat[] = $k;
                $stack[] = $v;
            }
            else {
                $flat[] = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    return $flat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next recursive function:

```
function array_flat($arr) {
    $res = [];
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            // element is array: Push key to result and merge recursion result
            array_push($res, $key);
            $res = array_merge($res, array_flat($val));
        } else {
            // push simple value to result
            array_push($res, $val);
        }
        
    }
    return $res;
}

print_r(array_flat($arr));
```

[Try working PHP code o PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=40efa18fba9181eed2eed94393030262&sqlses=5ae6d3bff497103b4b9a28fddbe8e79e&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)